# Comprehensive list of shellshock attack vectors

Tags: attack-vector, shellshock

Currently I know of three serious attack vectors:

1. crafted cgi parameters from a web client
2. dhclient getting crafted hostnames from a DHCP server
3. restricted SSH users getting full shell access

I realise this may be too wide of a question, but I did not find any such info as of yet, only vague guesses. (Maybe this question belong to the community wiki.)

I am interested mainly in:

1. client services like the dhclient
2. server services like the cgi/ssh attack
3. desktop clients accessing the network like a web browser, ftp client, etc. (i have not heard anything like that yet)

Comment: Essentially, anywhere than an attacker can control an environment variable is potentially vulnerable.

Comment: I am aware of and understand the generics. I am interested in the specific services that are exploitable, and should be watched.

Comment: Check https://isc.sans.edu/ reference links on their front page article as it should help address your query.

Comment: [This blog post](https://www.dfranke.us/posts/2014-09-27-shell-shock-exploitation-vectors.html) offers the most comprehensive list of attack vectors in actual software which I'm aware of so far.

Comment: @F30 that blog post was very informative

Comment: I am sadly aware that this is indeed a too broad question _by nature_. However, it is an important question and would like to know where I can ask it. Should I start a new question about that on meta, or is there a definitive place for these kinds of questions already?